# Optimizing a loop to cut down on the number of draws

Tags: javascript, optimization, internet-explorer-8

I'm creating an animated strip chart that redraws on every new packet message received from the header. First I create a function that checks if the chart already exists and if not builds it:

```
function drawAccel() {
    if (chart == null) {
      chart = Stripchart(document.getElementById('accel'));
    }

    if (orienteer == null) {
      orienteer = Orienteer(document.getElementById('orienteer'));
    }

    chart.draw();
    orienteer.draw();
}
```

Following that I run this function which loops and redraws the chart on every header packet recieved:

```
function messagecb(header, message) {
    if(header.type == 6) {
      // echo reply
      // processEchoReply(message);
    }else if(header.type == 4) {
      // accel
      var accels = message.b64UnpackAccelMsg();

      for(var index in accels) {
          var accel = accels[index];
          var totalClock = accelEpochAdjust(accel.clock);

          addAccelDatum(totalClock, accel.x,  accel.y, accel.z);
      }

      drawAccel();

} else if(header.type == 3) {
    // info
    var info2 = message.b64UnpackInfo2Msg();

    displayCurrentPosition(info2.fixtime, info2.lat, info2.lon, info2.alt);
    displayMobileStatus(info2.rssi, info2.bandClass, info2.batt);
} else if(header.type == 11) {
    btReceive(header, message);
  }
}
```

I have no issues in all the modern browsers using this method, but in IE8 it really slows down a lot. This causes a slow running script error to occur which eventually ends up breaking the app. I also think something about my current logic is causing the chart to redraw even if the graph hasn't visually changed, but I'm unsure of how to check on that. Sorry for being long winded any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe queue until you get 10 of them and then redraw?

Comment: how could I set up that queue though

Comment: This would be used between the messagecb and the draw function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error along with a little help from some one else this ended up solving the problem. Set a local variable rather than a global to act as a counter that can be checked to see if it is a multiple of 10. Wrap the draw function with it so that it draws on every tenth packet.

```
function messagecb(header, message) {
    if(header.type == 6) {
      // processEchoReply(message);

    } else if(header.type == 4) {
        var accels = message.b64UnpackAccelMsg();

    for(var index = 0; index < accels.length; ++index) {
        var accel = accels[index];
        var totalClock = accelEpochAdjust(accel.clock);

        addAccelDatum(totalClock, accel.x,  accel.y, accel.z);
    }

    if ( typeof messagecb.counter == 'undefined' ) {
      messagecb.counter = 0;
    }

    ++messagecb.counter;
    if (messagecb.counter % 10 == 0) {
      drawAccel();
    }

  } else if(header.type == 3) {
      // info
      var info2 = message.b64UnpackInfo2Msg();

      displayCurrentPosition(info2.fixtime, info2.lat, info2.lon, info2.alt);
      displayMobileStatus(info2.rssi, info2.bandClass, info2.batt);
  } else if(header.type == 11) {
      btReceive(header, message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be much help so please dont downvote.

I had a similar problem and only redrew every so many packets or over a set time frame like:

```
var mycars = new Array();
var count = 0;

function newPakcet(pck) {
    mycars[mycars.length + 1] = pck;
    redraw();
}
var redrawSize = 10;

function redraw(pck) {
    if (mycars.length > 10) {
        for(var i = 0 ;i < mycars.length;i++){
            //Draw here
        }
       mycars = new Array();
    }
}
```

Not tested it so there may be more syntax error.

Comment: Would you use this method to replace my messagecb function?

Comment: Did this method work well for you if the number of packets were variable?